# Index of a list item

Tags: python, list

I have a custom class that I have made. I make a list out of that class:

```
grid = []
def make_grid(r,c):
    global grid
    grid = [grid_object(x,y) for x in range(r) for y in range(c)]#Thanks Adam

make_grid(row, columns) #this makes the grid

class grid_object(object):#Thanks Adam
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y 
        self.item = "Blank"
        self.tag = "Nothing"
```

I want to hold a couple of grid's indexs for a side quest. Below I only showed one.

```
baby_grid = ''

def baby_side_quest():
    global grid
    global baby_grid

    baby_grid = [i for i, j in grid if j.tag == "Baby_Bear"]
    print baby_grid
```

I can get the baby_grid as a list. Here the code just prints:

>>>[2]

But what I really want is just:

>>> 2

How can I do that without having to write baby_grid[0] everywhere?

I just added this little function.

```
def get_int_from_list(list_thing):
    return list_thing[0]
```

I just wonder if there is a way that I don't know of that would make my code really concise. If you have a better way of doing this I'd love you see that code.

Comment: Yeah. I'm trying to avoid that. I have code that looks like this. `elif grid[mama_grid[0]].enemy_killed_bool == False and grid[papa_grid[0]].enemy_killed_bool == False:
grid[baby_grid[0]].been_here_text = "The baby bear is happy to still have both it's parents."
 `

Comment: Then you should include that information in your question.

Comment: Ohh sorry. I'll add it now.

Comment: what exactly is the issue? Your function call would take as much to call as writing the list name and slicing.

Comment: I didn't actually think of writing a function until after I posted this question. I'd been working on it for an hour and I just didn't see that as a solution.

Comment: is it simply avoiding typing the code, how much code the calls take up or why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: It was to make the code look shorter. It was getting long with the two checks and started getting overbearing for me. I'm still new to programming even though I have done it for a long time. I don't know where I need to make better code.

Comment: why is it in a list if you only have one item?

Comment: This code: `[i for i, j in grid if j.tag == "Baby_Bear"]` throws it into a list. I just what the number but I don't know how to get it.

Comment: I think the problems lie in your design, I see classes and globals mixed which is usually not a good sign. If you want to get a single value just use a normal loop.

Comment: What would that look like? `for i in grid if i.tag =="Baby_Bear"`

Comment: what happens if  `j.tag  != "Baby_bear"`?

Comment: Thay all start out as nothing in the grid_object(object)
`elif (grid_player_on.tag == "Nothing"): #nothing. True == True`
If they have anything else I print an error.
`else: print "Error in tag system"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will your `baby_grid` always only consist of one item? If so, you could simply do

```
baby_grid = [i for i, j in grid if j.tag == "Baby_Bear"][0]
```

Comment: if `j.tag != "Baby_Bear" you will get an index error and I think for a single value there are better ways to assign to a variable

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how pythonic it is considered, but you could do that the old fashioned way:

```
for i, j in grid:
    if j.tag == "Baby_Bear":
        return i
```